# How to search a column of names and make a decision based on whether the name has special characters on the end

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Must be able to identify special characters on end, specifically `*,**,***, +, ++`.
Must make a decision on whether there is one, two, three asterisks and one or two plus symbols.  For example:

```
Alston*
Jordon**
Baker***
Haskel+
Mike++
Tom
```

e.g. * might mean use cell X15, ** might mean use cel X16, etc.

Would like to use formulas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("*",A1)),"Cell has "&LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"*",""))&" *(s)",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("+",A1)),"Cell has "&LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"+",""))&" +(s)","No Special characters"))
```

[image]

Comment: You are a pro, no doubt.  I would have never come up with this formula, but then then that is the reason I reached out to stakoverflow.com.  Thank you.

Comment: @TommyG if this worked, please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.